# Can't find column object when filter() and str_detect()

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following data set:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("T", "F", "T"), b = c("USA", "SIG", "FRA"))
```

I want to filter out a subset whose `a` column value is `F`. I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(a, "F"))
```

But I got this `Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : object 'a' not found`.

Can anyone please help and give some explanation?

Comment: Are you sure you're evaluating the entire pipe?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure you have loaded both `dplyr` and `stringr`.

Comment: try filtering with grepl : `df1 %>% filter(grepl('F',a))`. (also, your code works for me too)

Comment: I already had some conflicts with `stats::filter`, try typing the full name `dplyr::filter`

Comment: @www Thanks for the reminder. I put `dplyr` and `stringr` in the same chunk and ran it, and it worked. It seems sometimes the packages I have `library()` will not work out and I have to ran them again? Is it better to library() package in every code chunks (repeatedly)?

Comment: thank you all, I learned other ways to to this because of your suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, good job on providing example code to work with, giving the error and proper formatting. Wish I can give you some sort of badge.

Your code is correct. You're not executing the entire block of code, therefore you get that error. You may be running an old version of R/RStudio, because in the recent version, `crtl+enter` on the `filter` command will execute the whole block of code. On older versions it doesn't behave this way.

Either select the enter code block and run it or have the code on a single line:

```
df %>%filter(str_detect(a, "F"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I alway press `command` + `enter` on my mac, does it work differently?

Comment: No, it's the same thing, different shortcut for a different system. Update Rstudio and see if it changes. Selecting the enter code is a sure way to execute it correctly